# mysql select into outfile without any line termination character

Tags: mysql, select, formatting, into-outfile, select-into-outfile

I try to print all the data from one field from a table into a file witout any line/field termination character. I would simply like to have all the rows concatenated and printed as one line in the output line. Here how I am doing it:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (txt VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ("text1");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ("text2");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ("text3");

SELECT txt FROM tbl;

SELECT txt INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY '' FROM tbl;
```

Unfortunely in the output I get tabs:

```
text1   text2   text3
```

if I add

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
```

then all the 100 characters are printed into file (VARCHAR(100)

```
text1                                                                                               text2                                                                                               text3
```

What should I do to get everything contcatenated as:

```
text1text2text3
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no spaces in text column itself,  try 
    SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(txt),',','') AS txt INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt' FROM tbl ;

If there are spaces in data then wrap one more REPLACE(   ,' ','') around

if you run into limit (how many rows are to be GROUP_CONCATinated then it's best to use following if you are using Unix like OS

```
cat 'test.txt' | tr -d '\t'
```

Comment: Hi Parag, thank you for your help! I actually was able to solve my problem thanks to your suggestion. I am going to post my sollution below in a second. I didn't undertstand your comment about SPACES in the text column. Why would SPACES matter if the default separator used by group_by is COMMA ',' and even if it was SPACE then why would wrapping it into one more REPLACE help? I need to do everything on the database level, so using tr is not an option. Anyway I am on Windows, so I couldn't even use it if I wanted to. Thank you once more for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Parag I was able to solve my problem, by using:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(txt SEPARATOR '') INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY '' FROM tbl;
```

This way I didn't have to wrap everything around with REPLACE and didn't bother if the text contains the default separator used by GROUP_CONCAT, which is COMMA ',' or not.

One important thing worth remembering is that GROUP_CONCAT() has a limit of maximum length, which you probalby run into when your fields are long. In my case the txt fields are over 900 characters, so I had to use:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000
```

This did the trick, but I wonder if there is any better sollution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a DUMPFILE:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (txt VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ("text1");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ("text2");
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ("text3");

SELECT txt FROM tbl;

SELECT txt INTO DUMPFILE 'test.txt';
```